# How to construct a new JSON from a fetch data response?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I would like to create a new JSON from a fetch data response.

For example, I am fetching https://api.tryroll.com/v2/tokens/ and

```
fetch('https://api.tryroll.com/v2/tokens/').then(response => {
return response.json()
})
```

would like to create a new JSON using the data like this:

```
"source": {
 "address": response.contractAddress
}
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify` creates JSON from an object

Comment: So you want an object called `source` and it has a single object called `address` and that object has a single property called `contractAddress` and it has the value of all the `contractAddress` keys from the original JSON? If so shouldn't all the values be better off in an array?

Answer (score 1):

we can use a JS map function to to get the contractAddress from the API response.

```
fetch ('https://api.tryroll.com/v2/tokens').then(res => {
  return res.json();
}).then (data => {
  const result = data.map(item => {
     return {
       "source": {
         "address": item.contractAddress
       }
     }
  }); 
  console.log(result);
});
```

With async await it would be like this

```
(async () => {
   const response = await fetch ('https://api.tryroll.com/v2/tokens');
   const data = await response.json();
   const result = data.map(item => {
     return {
       "source": {
         "address": item.contractAddress
       }
     }
   });
   console.log(result);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just needed to return that promise from fetch. I wasn't so sure how you wanted your data structure to look but this is what I came up with. I set the address to be a unique name and its value is the contractAddress.

```
var fetchData = function () {
  return fetch('https://api.tryroll.com/v2/tokens/').then(response => {
    return response.json();
  });
};

var myArray = {};

fetchData().then(data => {
  data.forEach(element => {

    console.log(element["name"]);
    myArray[element["name"]] = element.contractAddress;

  });
  console.log(myArray)
});
```

Answer (score -1):

When you are using fetch it returns a promise , so better use async function with await keyword or process the promise with then /catch block.

```
const res = fetch('https://api.tryroll.com/v2/tokens/').then(response => {
return response.json()
});

res.then((data)=>{ console.log(data) })
```

*data* will be a response in json format.

Comment: no it won't ... it will be an `Object` ... response.json() parses the JSON into an object ... fetch 101